# Put JS object in html <table>

Tags: javascript, html, object, html-table

I have a HTML `<form>` that collects 5 different types of data, this gets place in a Javascript object, which looks like this:

```
var memberObj = [
  {
  name: "testname",
  prof: "profession",
  level: 0,
  guild: "guild",
  server: "server",
  }
];
```

What I want to is take these object properties and place then into a table, which looks like this:

```
<table class="table table-striped" id="memberList">
  <tr>
    <th>Character name</th>
    <th>Profession</th>
    <th>Level</th>
    <th>Guild</th>
    <th>Server</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I basically want to create a new `<tr>` for each object and a new `<td>` for each `object.property`.

How should I go about doing this? I have looked around on Stack Overflow but not found anything that has helped me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use two `for` loops to iterate over objects, then columns.
Use jQuery's `append` function to add html code to the table

```
var cols = ['name', 'prof', 'level', 'guild', 'server'];

for (var i = 0; i < memberObj.length; i++) {
  $('table').append('<tr></tr>');

  for (var j = 0; j < cols.length; j++) {
    $('table tr:last-child').append('<td>' + memberObj[i][cols[j]] + '</td>');
  }
}
```

Check out a working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u38mokjr/6/)